# Javascript input type file issue with windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working with angularjs/javascript and trying to upload .vtt file using html `<input type="file">` tag. After selecting file i am firing a onchange event of javascript and getting file object of selected file. In linux i can get the .vtt type inside file object, but in windows system type field is coming blank. How can i get the file type in windows, or any permission needed in windows to get the file.
Here is a plunker i created for demo purpose :-
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/90Bkw9jU3uIVMb00tDEi?p=preview)
Thanks

Comment: include all relevant code to OP for demo use `<>`

Comment: @guradio check the console after select .vtt file. Here us can see type:"text/vtt". but in windows its coming blank,

Comment: You need to parse extension from name.
Some OS or Browser unable to return MIME TYPE of file.